# Send JWT token in address bar from Application A to Application B

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, authentication, jwt

I have Application A which have login screen. Once I successfully logged into Application A, I need to access application B without any authentication.

After successful login into Application A, I am requesting for jwt token from Application B with just username.

Can I send Jwt token in address url link for application B. So I can use the token in client browser.

Application B is developed using ReactJs as frontend and Spring Boot REST API as backend.

Is it safe to send JWT token as query parameter in address bar.

Comment: Rather than sending it in parm, send it in header (Authorization or your custom header if you want to).

Comment: As @Silverfang mentioned, the practice is to send it in the header. About safety, it's not that sending in headers make it safe or sending in URL makes unsafe. JWTs are verified based using signature at backend

Comment: @Silverfang, I need to store the token in browser localstorage or cookies. My front end is reactjs, so I wont be be able to get header values.